# Change color based on even / odd answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that I'd like the color to switch depending on what the value is, either **odd**, **even** or just **0**. I've search on stackoverflow for some answers but none really helped..
So, if the answer is odd, the color shall be blue. If the answer is even, the color shall be red. If the answer is 0, the color shall be yellow.

Any clues that could help me keep going?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #0D1112;
 
    }
    
    form {
      display: flex;
      height: 30px;
      gap: 30px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    p {
      color: white;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #svar {
      background-color: #0D1112;
    }
    
    h4 {
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="f0rm">
    <input name="nummer1" id="nummer1" type="text" size="5">
    <select id="dropDown" name="thing" id="dropID">
      <option>choose</option>
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="x">x</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
    </select>
    <input name="nummer2" id="nummer2" type="text" size="5"> =
    <input type="button" id="calculator" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <div id="svar">
    <p>Your answer is...</p>
    <h4>Blue = odd answer</h4>
    <h4>Red = even answer</h4>
    <h4>Yellow = your answer is just 0</h4>
  </div>



  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#calculator').click(function() {
        var value = $("#dropDown").val();
        var number1 = $("#nummer1").val();
        var number2 = $("#nummer2").val();
        var int1 = parseInt(number1);
        var int2 = parseInt(number2);
        if (value === "+") $("#svar p").text(int1 + int2);
        else if (value === "-") $("#svar p").text(int1 - int2);
        else if (value === "/") $("#svar p").text(int1 / int2);
        else if (value === "x") $("#svar p").text(int1 * int2);

        if (value % 2 == 0)
          $("#svar p").css("background-color", "red")

        else(value % 2 == 1)
        $("#svar p").css("background-color", "blue")

      });

    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You mean `else if`

Comment: Hi! I tried to change "else" to "else if" but now it stopped working instead. :-(. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Read the error log in the console or your IDE

Comment: There are a lot of problems here. First, `value` is not a number so doing `value % 2` will result in NaN, i.e never 1 or 0. The reason it's turning blue is because your `else` is ignoring the condition because `else` doesn't take a condition and `value % 2` will never be equal to 0. This should be an `else if`. Lastly, you're not even checking for 0 so it will never be yellow.

Comment: That's a well written advice! I'm new to javascript (or is this jquery?). I'll try tweaking it a bit as you told me to!

Comment: This is JavaScript. JQuery is a library for JavaScript that adds a bunch of methods that can simplify your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just debugged your code a little bit

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #0D1112;
 
    }
    
    form {
      display: flex;
      height: 30px;
      gap: 30px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    p {
      color: white;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #svar {
      background-color: #0D1112;
    }
    
    h4 {
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="f0rm">
    <input name="nummer1" id="nummer1" type="text" size="5">
    <select id="dropDown" name="thing" id="dropID" required>
      <option>choose</option>
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="x">x</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
    </select>
    <input name="nummer2" id="nummer2" type="text" size="5"> =
    <input type="button" id="calculator" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <div id="svar">
    <p>Your answer is...</p>
    <h4>Blue = odd answer</h4>
    <h4>Red = even answer</h4>
    <h4>Yellow = your answer is just 0</h4>
  </div>



  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#calculator').click(function() {
        var value = $("#dropDown").val();
        var number1 = $("#nummer1").val();
        var number2 = $("#nummer2").val();
        var int1 = parseInt(number1);
        var int2 = parseInt(number2);
          
        let result = 0;
        
        if (value === "+") result = int1 + int2;
        else if (value === "-") result = int1 - int2;
        else if (value === "/") result = int1 / int2;
        else if (value === "x") result = int1 * int2;
        
        $("#svar p").text(result)

        if (result % 2 == 0){
          $("#svar p").css("background-color", "red");
        } else {
          $("#svar p").css("background-color", "blue");
        }
      });

    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How kind of you. Btw why did you declare result = 0? Also, why did you use "let" instead of "var"? Thanks!

Comment: @HTML_Newbie that's because you're repeating code, it's easier and more readable to declare a variable, assign the result to that variable and at the end assign the result to the element. The answer for the second question is because nowadays is not recommended to use "var" due to have a better scope. I recommend you to read about ES6 and ES5 differences.